# How to override cartcontroller in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart, overrides, controllers

I want to override cartcontroller(checkout/controller/cart.php) by my module controller. Can anyone help me please? Any help will be appreciated.

I just tried, But it is not working. My files are,

\code \StwBuyXGetY \BuyXGetY \etc\di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart"
             type="StwBuyXGetY\BuyXGetY\Controller\Checkout\Cart" />
</config>
```

\code \StwBuyXGetY \BuyXGetY \Controller\Checkout\Cart.php

```
<?php
namespace StwBuyXGetY\BuyXGetY\Controller\Checkout;
class Cart extends \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart
{
    public function execute(){
        echo 'Hello World'; exit;}
}
```

Please help. (Note:- I just put the dummy content in cart.php, this is not the actual function.)

Comment: http://webkul.com/blog/overriding-block-model-controller-magento2/, http://blog.a2bizz.com/index.php/2015/12/31/magento-2-overriding-controller/. Checkout these links for overriding controller.

Comment: I removed the complete var folder, but that is not helping.

Answer (score 5):

First of all...I advice against rewriting controllers.
Actually I advice against rewriting anything if you can do it an other way.
Second:  The class `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart` is an abstract class. It is never instantiated so you cannot rewrite it.
I assume you want to replace the behavior of the `execute` method from one of the classes that extend `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart`.
If so, you can do it with an [`around` plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html#around-methods) for your `execute` method in the original controller.
Let's take for example `Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add` controller action

For this you will need to add this to the `di.xml` of your module:

```
 <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add">
    <plugin name="buy-x-get-y" type="StwBuyXGetY\BuyXGetY\Plugin\Controller\Checkout\Cart\Add" sortOrder="1" />
</type>
```

Then create the file `StwBuyXGetY/BuyXGetY/Plugin/Controller/Checkout/Cart/Add.php` with this content:

```
namespace StwBuyXGetY\BuyXGetY\Plugin\Controller\Checkout\Cart;
class Add
{
    public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $add, \callable $proceed)
    {
        //your code goes here
        //if you don't want the original method to be called ignore what'e below.
        $returnValue = $proceed();
        return $returnValue;
    }
}
```

I haven't tested the code, so look out for typos.

Comment: Hi @Marius, I edited my question, could you please check it???

Comment: @Keerthana. You edited the question adding an unrelated question to it. Please keep them separate. If you have an additional question please [ask an it here](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask)

Comment: I have posted another question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/131716/how-to-override-cart-addcontroller-in-magento-2 and edited this one. Please check.