# How to override cart\addcontroller in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cart, overrides, controllers, addtocart

I want this function in `\code \StwBuyXGetY \BuyXGetY \Controller\Checkout\Cart\Add.php`(this is written in magento 1.9, I want to convert it into magento 2). But I cant add any new function in add controller. Any help will be appreciated.

```
    public function buyXgetYfree()
    {


        $cart = $this->_getCart();
        /* check if cart is empty */
        if (!$this->_getCart()->getQuote()->getItemsCount()) {

            return;
        }       


        $buyProductXID = explode (",",Mage::getStoreConfig('buyxgety_section1/general/productx_product_id'));
        $buyProductYID = explode (",",Mage::getStoreConfig('buyxgety_section1/general/producty_product_id'));
        $buyProductXminQty = explode (",",Mage::getStoreConfig('buyxgety_section1/general/productx_required_qty'));
        $buyProductXmaxQty = explode (",",Mage::getStoreConfig('buyxgety_section1/general/productx_limit_qty'));    
        $buyProductYDescription = explode (",",Mage::getStoreConfig('buyxgety_section1/general/producty_description'));

        $error="A BuyXGetY Extension cart error was detected!";     

        try
        {
            for($i = 0; $i < count($buyProductXID); $i++){
                if (empty($buyProductYDescription[$i])) {
                    $buyProductYDescription[$i]="free gift";
                }
                if (empty($buyProductXID[$i])) {
                    $buyProductXID[$i]="0";
                }
                if (empty($buyProductYID[$i])) {
                    $buyProductYID[$i]="0";
                }
                if (empty($buyProductXminQty[$i])) {
                    $buyProductXminQty[$i]="999";
                }
                if (empty($buyProductXmaxQty[$i])) { 
                    $buyProductXmaxQty[$i]="0";
                }               
                if ($buyProductXID[$i] !="0" && $buyProductYID[$i] !="0") { 
                    if ($this->isProductYUnique()) 
                    {

                        $this->buyXgetYfreeCartUpdate((int)$buyProductXID[$i],(int)$buyProductXminQty[$i],(int)$buyProductYID[$i],$buyProductYDescription[$i],(int)$buyProductXmaxQty[$i]);             
                    } else {    
                        $error = "Error in Buy X configuration - Product Y is not unique across all extension settings.";   
                        throw new Exception($error);
                        break;
                    }
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception $ex) { 

            $cart->getCheckoutSession()->addError($this->__($error));
            $this->sendErrorEmail($error);
            }
    }
```

**di.xml**

```
        <?xml version="1.0"?>
        <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
        <type name="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add">
            <plugin name="buy-x-get-y" type="StwBuyXGetY\BuyXGetY\Plugin\Controller\Checkout\Cart\Add" sortOrder="1" />
        </type>
        </config>
```

**\code \StwBuyXGetY \BuyXGetY \Controller\Checkout\Cart\Add.php**

```
        namespace StwBuyXGetY\BuyXGetY\Plugin\Controller\Checkout\Cart;
        class Add
        {
            public function aroundExecute(\Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $add, \callable $proceed, OutputInterface $output)
            {
                $this->buyXgetYfree();
                $returnValue = $proceed();
                return $returnValue;
            }
            public function buyXgetYfree()
            {
                echo "buyXgetYfree"; // this is dummy content
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your plugin controller to following

```
class Add
{
    public function aroundExecute(
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\Add $subject,
        \Closure $proceed
    ) {
        $this->buyXgetYfree();
        return $proceed();
    }

    public function buyXgetYfree()
    {
        error_log('buyXgetYfree');
    }
}
```

When you press addtocart button, basically it's not return any 'echo' content. So you can use error_log or magento 2 log system for checking.

Comment: this solution is not working for me, error log is not displaying.

Answer (score 1):

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/addToCart.log');
    $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
    $logger->addWriter($writer);
    $logger->debug(__METHOD__);
```

Sohel is right, it does not show your echo if you try to add to cart. You can try this one and check your log at var/log/addToCart.log